# Visual Studio 2013 Lag and Errors

Tags: setup, visual-studio-2013

After recently downloading Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional, I can't work on any projects due to lag. After I open up a project, there is a large delay between any of my actions. I have already searched about this, and people mostly say that it is a graphics driver issue that can be resolved by turning off the usage of accelerated graphics OR downloading Visual Studio Update 1, which is supposed to fix this. Also, whenever I wish to close out of Visual Studio, I get an error saying: "An error ocurred while creating or opening the C++ browsing database file" and then: "Ensure that Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 is installed." I searched this too, and attempted to download SQL Server Compact 4.0, but the setup said that a later version was already installed, then it aborted. I have uninstalled and tried to repair Visual Studio as well. Any help is very much appreciated, as I have spent many hours trying to debug this to no avail. I also know for a fact that is NOT my computer that is causing lag, it is Visual Studio.

*It should also be noted that the lag only occurs when a solution is currently loaded.

Comment: "can be resolved by turning off the usage of accelerated graphics OR downloading Visual Studio Update 1" So, did you try either of these? If instead of opening an existing project you start a new one, does it work as expected?   For the existing projects you're having problems with, were they ever using in VS2013?  Does renaming, moving or deleting the .SUO file (before opening the solution in VS) for the project help any?

Comment: Based on the error you have some installation that is corrupt getting an error when you close Visual Studio is not normal

Comment: @techie007 I tried turning off the graphics acceleration and updating, but that didn't help. When I start a new project, it lags and gives the error on exit. Same as with opening an old one. And I can't seem to find any .SUO file either.